# Dynamically create ASPxButtons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a download list where each available file has its own ASPxButton and I would like to dynamically create them rather than creating like 30 manually and dynamically setting them to visible.

Since I don't have a form within my .aspx.cs file but create my buttons within a table in my .aspx code, I can't use the form.AddButton method. Any ideas on how to do something like that?

Not sure if that helps but here is the code for the 2 buttons I already have:

```
<dx:TabPage Name="Downloads" Text="Downloads" Enabled="false">
            <ContentCollection>
                <dx:ContentControl runat="server">
                    <table class="grid_centered">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnDownload0" runat="server" Text="Anschreiben" Theme="Metropolis" CssClass="button centered" OnClick="btn_Click" Width="300px"></dx:ASPxButton>                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnDownload1" runat="server" Text="Serie 1" Theme="Metropolis" CssClass="button centered" OnClick="btn_Click" Width="300px" Visible="false" Enabled="false"></dx:ASPxButton>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </dx:ContentControl>
            </ContentCollection>
        </dx:TabPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is to use an `asp:Repeater`. This way, I only have to write the details for one and use the `OnItemCommand` event to handle button clicks. I had to switch to using `asp:Button` instead of `dx:ASPxButton`, though since I needed the `CommandName` field to pass the info which button was pressed along to my event handler.

```
<asp:Repeater
    ID="MyRepeater"
    runat="server"
    DataSourceID="MyDataSource"
    OnItemCommmand="MyClickedEventHandler">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button
            ID="MyButton"
            runat="server"
            Text="Download"
            CommandName='<%# $"{Eval("keyField")}" %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with dx:ASPxButton but I am assuming it would be similar to an aspx:Button. To dynamically create controls you have to create the controls in the Page_Load() event.

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
    //get your files
    string targetDirectory = "your directory";
    string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);    
    int i = 0;
    foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
        ASPxButton btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = fileName;
        btn.ID = "btnDownload" + i.ToString();
        btn.CssClass = "button centered";
        btn.Attributes.Add("Theme", "Metropolis");
        //add any other properties you need

        //add the event handler
        btn.Click += new EvenHandler(btn_Clik);
        form.AddButton(btn);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't have a form in my C# code to add the buttons to. All the buttons are only created in the aspx code and only connected to the c# code via the OnClick attribute which triggers their respective event. Any clue how to circumvent using c# forms?

Comment: You can add the controls to your Table by adding it to a table cell. You would have add an "id" and a "runat" attribute on your table and then you would be able to access the table in the code behind. The [TableCell Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) has a good example.  Sorry for the late response.

Comment: I forgot that you might need to do "Table table = Page.FindControl("table_id") as Table;" in order to get access to the table.